# Is a function $f\colon C\to\mathbb{R}$ bounded if $C$ is compact but $f$ is not necessarily continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness

If I have a function mapping a compact set to the real numbers, is that function bounded? I know that this is true if the function is continuous. But is it true even if the function is not continuous? If so, how do I prove this?

Comment: Can you show that on any infinite set  there is an unbounded real valued function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ if $x \neq 0$ and $f(0) = 2$. Then $f$ is unbounded but its domain $[0,1]$ is compact.